# C++ SOL3 : Efficiently assigning a C++ stored table to a global table

Tags: c++, sol3

In C++, I have a vector of sol::table stored:

```
std::vector<sol::table> vecInstLuaTable;
```

At some point in my code, I want to assign one of these tables to a global table called `"me"` :

```
XEROOM::EXPOSED::SetScopeT(CURRENTROOMPTR->vecInstLuaTable[index]);
XELUASTATE::RunFunction(func);
XEROOM::EXPOSED::ResetScope();

void SetScopeT(const sol::table& t) {
    vecStackScope.push_back(lua["me"]);
    lua["me"] = t;
}

void ResetScope() {
    lua["me"] = vecStackScope.back();
    vecStackScope.pop_back();
}
```

The functions `SetScopeT()` and `ResetScope()` apparently take quite the amount of time. I understand that lua-C++ interop is not a free ride, but I have 2 questions about it:

Apparently in `SetScopeT()`, using a `const sol::table&` parameter instead of a `sol::table` improves performance by a lot. Why though? Isn't `sol::table` a masqueraded reference by itself? Same goes by using `sol::protected_function&` and `sol::protected_function` elsewhere.
Is the method described above efficient or am I doing something unbelievably stupid for such a simple task? If so, what's the best (fastest) way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

"The functions SetScopeT() and ResetScope() apparently take quite the amount of time"

From the C++ perspective, there are only two important categories of operations: the lookup of `lua["me"]` (trivial optimization: do it once in `SetScopeT`) and value operations (copy/assign) on a `sol::table`. Since you say that it takes a lot of time, it seems entirely expected that adding another copy (for pass-by-value) makes it even slower.

What's easily fixed: you're using `vecStackScope` as a stack. That means you have the occasional vector reallocation. This can be avoided by moving to `std::list`. You're losing the random-access performance, but you don't use that anyway.